# Filtering a dropdown list as typing, without use of ActiveX for desktop Excel

Tags: excel, vba, keypress

I am trying to accomplish KeyPress trigger for a cell that is a named range and has data validation applied.

Even the simple vba setup code would be in Worksheet_Change:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("A1")
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="myData", RefersTo:=rng
With Range("myData")
    With .Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=myList"            
    End With
End With
```

However the below code never gets called, when its in a Module of the workbook

```
Private Sub myData_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    MsgBox "Win"
End Sub
```

Update a non-ActiveX form that will provide a dropdown list to select from based on value being typed in, and auto-updates with a new list that is filtered based on value entered so far

Comment: Why do you think that a named range, even list validated, exposes any event? Is there any secret documentation stating about that, and we did not here about it?

Comment: I haven't looked in any detail, but for a start you don't have a myData object, so myData_KeyPress will never handle any events

Comment: @FaneDuru so events will only work with controls?

Comment: @CallumDA I added the bit of code `, RefersTo:=Rng`

Comment: Not only with controls. They works with object exposing them (also sheet, workbook, charts...) A cell does not expose any event. You can catch its change using **sheet** `Change` (`SelectionChange` etc.) event(s)...

Comment: @FaneDuru I am trying to create a KeyPress event for a specific cell

Comment: You may try sending people in space (using VBA), but you will obtain a similar return. **What do you really want accomplishing**? Forgot about event and tell us which is your need. I suppose that you are not in love with this event... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru The desktop version of excel for windows does not update a dropdown list as you type. And Microsoft is the only one that supports ActiveX. Therefore to have a dropdown list (list of states) that is connected to a cell and will update the dropdown list as you type requires a KeyPress event from everything I have been trying. And I want this dropdown list to update as you type, and be supported even on Apply machines

Comment: What do you mean by "does not update a dropdown list as you type"? A cell validated list cannot update itself. You can only select/choose one of its (list) options. When a cell is in edit mode (when you type in it), VBA wait for you to finish entering text and pressing Enter. You maybe want using a combo box (ActiveX) object... I kept asking what you **really** want accomplishing and without describing it (in details), I am afraid you cannot be helped. You must help us understanding what you want doing... It may not be possible, but without knowing what you ar talking about, we cannot help...

Comment: @FaneDuru A data validation list is only viewed when you click the dropdown arrow, which would display the list source range that is defined. My list is a spill list that is created from the following three steps `=SEARCH(C6,G6:G57)` `=ISNUMBER(H6)` `=FILTER(G6:G57,I6:I57)` copied down the list of states in cells I6:I57. If I enter a character in my entry cell I must click the arrow to update and display new list. In which I would like the update and display to occur as I type.

Comment: I am afraid you do not understand how such a validated cell works... If you try entering **any string not existing in the VALIDATED list**, it will not allow doing it! This is the behavior which Excel invented for it and its main "job". So, I am afraid I cannot understand what you want accomplishing. It is late in my country and I will close my laptop. I wish you luck in finding somebody else knowing how you can solve what you try explaining. Have a nice day!

Comment: As FaneDuru I am unsure what you mean by "update and display new list" - I am guessing what your need might be: If you want to achieve _autotyping_ (i.e. type e.g. D and then the first D-entry of your list is selected) you have to go with an ActiveX-control plus programming. A validation list won't do that. If you want the validation list to _open automatically_ whenever you click in the according cell - you have to put code into the worksheet_selectionchange-event. If you want to display the _values from your spill-list_ you have to create a name and apply that to the validation lists formula

Comment: @Ike No, that is called auto-complete. I am looking for a dropdown list to auto update and display as typing. ActiveX worked for me however it is not supported by Apple, and I am needing something that works on all platforms. This person mentions its already available online but not on desktop https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsL57bvd7Pk

Comment: But _what_ should get updated as your are typing? That's not clear to me. -- ok got it after watching the video - but that is kind of "autotyping" - you are _filtering_ not updating the validation list ...

Comment: the, or "a", dropdown list for a cell that gives you an option to choose from, displays a spill list that works in the background and updates as you type, reducing options based on cell contains what has been typed. Since a validation list does not offer keypress, and activeX forms are not an option, is there any other form that can be used to update a list as you type and auto display the new dropdown list that is selectable?

Comment: The problem is that your spill list will only update when you exit the cell with the validation list ...

Comment: @Ike correct that is the current situation. I wanted a vba script that would process the new value as typing, and not having to leave the cell, to update and display the dropdown list (not having to click a dropdown arrow by the user); hence the KeyPress action